# Use System.import to load react component asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load React component asynchronously, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
//import Home from '$components/Home/Home'

/**
 * Home Page container, loads at `/` route.
 */
class HomeContainer extends Component {

  /**
   * React Lifecycle Event: Renders Home Page View
   * @return {JSX}  Calls Home Component to Render the page
   */
  render() {
    return System.import('javascripts/components/Home/Home')
      .then(function (Home) {
        return <Home />
      })
  }
}

export default HomeContainer
```

Not sure what is going wrong. Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

React render will already just execute when it is appropriate.

You can use `require` instead to import the file inside the `render` function.

```
const component = require('component');
```

**Example:**

https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/components/SurveyForm/SurveyForm.js#L50

Comment: Webpack won't create a separate chunk in this way.